# Creating Holes all around Mesh

Tags: modeling, topology, 3d-printing

I'd like to model a shoe that has holes all over its mesh, can be something like hexagons, triangles, or quads. How can I model something similar to this in Blender: [image: TPU Duck with Holes]

I was considering creating the shapes pattern using an array and then using bool tools to subtract it from the mesh, but I want the shape to appear parallel to every side of the mesh's surface.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Wireframe* modifier will give something close to what you want (with a *Subdivision Surface* to round the shapes), but the result will completely depend on your topology:

[image]